# Prestashop - PayPal USA - Order confirmation page skipped, goes to order history

Tags: paypal, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Prestashop 1.6.4.1, I install the module paypalusa (already in the modules directory) - it charge the user but doesn't create the order in prestashop.

I found this https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/419632-paypal-no-order-in-bo-order-history-fix/?p=1981130 with a link to this https://www.prestashop.com/forums/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=155300

This module is working, but it let you choose only one currency - we need multiple currencies.

we tried to install http://addons.prestashop.com/en/payment-card-wallet/1748-paypal.html (which is the only module in addons.prestashop.com for paypal) and it says `Your country is not available for this module please go on Prestashop addons to see the different possibilities.`

we bought the following module http://addons.prestashop.com/en/payment-card-wallet/5314-paypal-direct-payments.html
but it has only direct payment by credit card.

Please help on how to setup paypal for prestashop 1.6 with payment for multiple currencies.

EDIT:
I ended up using the module in this link - https://www.prestashop.com/forums/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=155300

I fixed it to use multi currency, how ever I think the bug was caused by a code change on my side that causes a change in the cart total sum, but when the paypal module returned it still compared to the old sum - the bug is a actually that it doesn't display a proper message.

Answer (score 0):

Some PayPal plugins will have some bugs.

Please try to use this one:
http://addons.prestashop.com/en/payment-card-wallet/1748-paypal.html

If doesnt work well: choose "United States" in your Shop Config as a main contact country